# React - Adding a default Option while using map in Select Tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I learnt that when using `Select` each element in the dropdown is given by `Option` tag.

Now i have an array of values the dropdown must contain-

```
a = ['hai','hello','what']
```

So i optimised my code by writing it as follows -

```
     <Select>  
          a.map(ele =>
        <Option value={ele}> ele </Option> )
     </Select>
```

This worked successfully. But now i want to add a default value to be shown on first render. 
I tried doing this -

```
<Select>
      <Option selected={true}> Choose from the list</Option
      a.map(ele =>
            <Option value={ele}> ele </Option> )
</Select>
```

But this gives an error. What is the right way to do it?

Comment: is your code correct?

Comment: what error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

React recommends using default value. If you replace selected with defaultValue you can solve the problem.

```js
<select>
<option defaultValue={true}>Choose From List</option>
{
    a.map((ele,index)) => <option key={index}>{ele}</option>
}
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the second parameter of the `map` for the index. And the `index === 0` then it would be selected.

```
<Select>
      <Option value=""> Choose from the list</Option
      a.map((ele, index) => <Option value={ele} selected={index === 0}> {ele} </Option>)
</Select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```js
<Select name="select" id="select" >
    {
        a.map(ele => (
            <option key={ele} >{ele}</option>
        ))
    }
</Select>
```